# $ is undefined, jQuery is undefined and AJS.$ is undefined

Tags: jquery, jira-plugin

I'm trying to write a jira gadget. Along with it, I'm using a third party jqplot scripts. I'm getting $ is undefined for everything is those scripts. see the libraries included and loading into my page here:

```
<link href="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.5.5/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.auiplugin:ajs-gadgets-base/basic.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.5.5/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.auiplugin:ajs-gadgets-base/dropdown.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.5.5/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.auiplugin:ajs-gadgets-base/icons.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.5.5/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.auiplugin:ajs-gadgets-base/tables.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.5.5/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.auiplugin:ajs-gadgets-base/forms.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.5.5/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.auiplugin:ajs-gadgets-base/messages.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.5.5/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.auiplugin:ajs/firebug.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.5.5/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.auiplugin:ajs/dialog.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.5.5/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.auiplugin:ajs/inline-dialog.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.5.5/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.auiplugin:ajs/tabs.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.5.5/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.auiplugin:ajs/toolbar.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.1.21/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.gadgets.publisher:ajax/ajax.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.1.21/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.gadgets.publisher:ajs-gadgets/common.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.1.21/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.gadgets.publisher:ajs-gadgets-lite/common.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/1.0/_/download/resources/jira.webresources:util-lite/icons.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/1.0/_/download/resources/jira.webresources:util-lite/gadgets-common.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/5.0.7/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.jira.gadgets:common-lite/base.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/5.0.7/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.jira.gadgets:common-lite/common.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/1.0/_/download/resources/jira.webresources:inline-layer/layer.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/1.0/_/download/resources/jira.webresources:autocomplete/autocomplete.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/5.0.7/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.jira.gadgets:autocomplete/layer.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/1.0-SNAPSHOT/_/download/resources/com.teradata.jira.gadgets.defectgadget:defectgadget-resources/defectgadget.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/1.0-SNAPSHOT/_/download/resources/com.teradata.jira.gadgets.defectgadget:defectgadget-resources/jqplot.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.5.5/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.auiplugin:jquery-lib/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.5.5/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.auiplugin:jquery-compatibility/jquery-compatibility.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.5.5/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.auiplugin:aui-core/atlassian.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.5.5/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.auiplugin:ajs-gadgets-base/jquery.aop.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.5.5/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.auiplugin:ajs-gadgets-base/dropdown.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.5.5/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.auiplugin:ajs/raphael.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.5.5/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.auiplugin:ajs/raphael.shadow.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.5.5/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.auiplugin:ajs/jquery.os.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.5.5/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.auiplugin:ajs/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.5.5/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.auiplugin:ajs/jquery-ui-1.7-bug-fixes.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.5.5/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.auiplugin:ajs/jquery.form.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.5.5/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.auiplugin:ajs/jquery.hotkeys.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.5.5/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.auiplugin:ajs/jquery.moveto.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.5.5/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.auiplugin:ajs/context-path.cp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.5.5/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.auiplugin:ajs/event.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.5.5/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.auiplugin:ajs/cookie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.5.5/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.auiplugin:ajs/dialog.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.5.5/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.auiplugin:ajs/icons.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.5.5/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.auiplugin:ajs/inline-dialog.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.5.5/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.auiplugin:ajs/firebug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.5.5/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.auiplugin:ajs/forms.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.5.5/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.auiplugin:ajs/messages.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.5.5/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.auiplugin:ajs/tabs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.5.5/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.auiplugin:ajs/template.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.5.5/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.auiplugin:ajs/whenitype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.5.5/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.auiplugin:ajs/toolbar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.5.5/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.auiplugin:ajs/jquery.autocomplete.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.5.5/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.auiplugin:ajs/jquery.is-dirty.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.5.5/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.auiplugin:ajs/jquery.progressbar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.5.5/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.auiplugin:ajs/jquery.selection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.5.5/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.auiplugin:ajs/jquery.throbber.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.1.21/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.gadgets.publisher:templates/soyutils.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.1.21/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.gadgets.publisher:templates/error.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.1.21/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.gadgets.publisher:templates/warning.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.1.21/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.gadgets.publisher:templates/info.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.1.21/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.gadgets.publisher:util/namespace.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.1.21/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.gadgets.publisher:util/util.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.1.21/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.gadgets.publisher:util/sysMsg.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.1.21/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.gadgets.publisher:ajax/mockXHR.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.1.21/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.gadgets.publisher:ajax/makeRequestToJQueryAjaxCallbackTransformer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.1.21/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.gadgets.publisher:ajax/mapToMakeRequestOptions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.1.21/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.gadgets.publisher:ajax/OAuth.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.1.21/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.gadgets.publisher:ajax/trustedApps.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.1.21/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.gadgets.publisher:ajax/anonymous.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.1.21/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.gadgets.publisher:ajax/jQuery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.1.21/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.gadgets.publisher:ajax/ajax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.1.21/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.gadgets.publisher:ajax/events.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.1.21/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.gadgets.publisher:ajs-gadgets/templater.namespace.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.1.21/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.gadgets.publisher:ajs-gadgets/ajs.gadgets.templater.base.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.1.21/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.gadgets.publisher:ajs-gadgets/ajs.gadgets.templater.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.1.21/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.gadgets.publisher:ajs-gadgets/ajs.gadgets.templater.form.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.1.21/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.gadgets.publisher:ajs-gadgets/ajs.gadgets.templater.table.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.1.21/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.gadgets.publisher:ajs-gadgets/form.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.1.21/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.gadgets.publisher:ajs-gadgets/table.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.1.21/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.gadgets.publisher:ajs-gadgets/events.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.1.21/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.gadgets.publisher:ajs-gadgets/gadgets.namespace.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.1.21/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.gadgets.publisher:ajs-gadgets/ajs.gadget.base.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.1.21/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.gadgets.publisher:ajs-gadgets/ajs.gadget.standard.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.1.21/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.gadgets.publisher:ajs-gadgets/ajs.gadget.configured.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.1.21/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.gadgets.publisher:ajs-gadgets/ajs.gadget.configurable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.1.21/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.gadgets.publisher:ajs-gadgets/ajs.gadget.factory.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.1.21/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.gadgets.publisher:ajs-gadgets/gadget-common-fields.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.1.21/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.gadgets.publisher:ajs-gadgets-lite/templater.namespace.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.1.21/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.gadgets.publisher:ajs-gadgets-lite/ajs.gadgets.templater.base.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.1.21/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.gadgets.publisher:ajs-gadgets-lite/ajs.gadgets.templater.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.1.21/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.gadgets.publisher:ajs-gadgets-lite/ajs.gadgets.templater.form.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.1.21/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.gadgets.publisher:ajs-gadgets-lite/ajs.gadgets.templater.table.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.1.21/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.gadgets.publisher:ajs-gadgets-lite/form.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.1.21/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.gadgets.publisher:ajs-gadgets-lite/table.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.1.21/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.gadgets.publisher:ajs-gadgets-lite/events.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.1.21/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.gadgets.publisher:ajs-gadgets-lite/gadgets.namespace.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.1.21/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.gadgets.publisher:ajs-gadgets-lite/ajs.gadget.base.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.1.21/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.gadgets.publisher:ajs-gadgets-lite/ajs.gadget.standard.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.1.21/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.gadgets.publisher:ajs-gadgets-lite/ajs.gadget.configured.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.1.21/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.gadgets.publisher:ajs-gadgets-lite/ajs.gadget.configurable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.1.21/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.gadgets.publisher:ajs-gadgets-lite/ajs.gadget.factory.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.1.21/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.gadgets.publisher:ajs-gadgets-lite/gadget-common-fields.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/1.0/_/download/resources/jira.webresources:util-lite/describeBrowser.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/1.0/_/download/resources/jira.webresources:util-lite/copyObject.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/1.0/_/download/resources/jira.webresources:util-lite/util.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/1.0/_/download/resources/jira.webresources:util-lite/trace.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/1.0/_/download/resources/jira.webresources:util-lite/meta.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/1.0/_/download/resources/jira.webresources:util-lite/Class.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/1.0/_/download/resources/jira.webresources:util-lite/Control.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/1.0/_/download/resources/jira.webresources:util-lite/Descriptor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/1.0/_/download/resources/jira.webresources:util-lite/Keyboard.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/1.0/_/download/resources/jira.webresources:util-lite/Mouse.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/1.0/_/download/resources/jira.webresources:util-lite/getOptionsFromAttributes.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/1.0/_/download/resources/jira.webresources:util-lite/SmartAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/1.0/_/download/resources/jira.webresources:util-lite/LayerManager.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/1.0/_/download/resources/jira.webresources:util-lite/hasFixedParent.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/5.0.7/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.jira.gadgets:common-lite/gadget-common.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/5.0.7/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.jira.gadgets:common-lite/gadget-common-fields.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/1.0/_/download/resources/jira.webresources:browser-properties/Navigator.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/1.0/_/download/resources/jira.webresources:util/observer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/1.0/_/download/resources/jira.webresources:util/aui-experimental.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/1.0/_/download/resources/jira.webresources:util/getDocHeight.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/1.0/_/download/resources/jira.webresources:util/os.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/1.0/_/download/resources/jira.webresources:util/JSONiefix.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/1.0/_/download/resources/jira.webresources:util/version.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/1.0/_/download/resources/jira.webresources:util/JSON.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/1.0/_/download/resources/jira.webresources:util/parseUri.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/1.0/_/download/resources/jira.webresources:util/effects.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/1.0/_/download/resources/jira.webresources:util/parseOptionsFromFieldset.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/1.0/_/download/resources/jira.webresources:util/handleAccessKeys.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/1.0/_/download/resources/jira.webresources:util/setSelectionRange.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/1.0/_/download/resources/jira.webresources:util/jquery.pjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/1.0/_/download/resources/jira.webresources:util/SessionStorage.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/1.0/_/download/resources/jira.webresources:util/LocalStorage.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/1.0/_/download/resources/jira.webresources:util/persistence.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/1.0/_/download/resources/jira.webresources:util/XSRF.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/1.0/_/download/resources/jira.webresources:util/bindDefaultCustomEvent.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/1.0/_/download/resources/jira.webresources:content-retrievers/ContentRetriever.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/1.0/_/download/resources/jira.webresources:content-retrievers/AjaxContentRetriever.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/1.0/_/download/resources/jira.webresources:content-retrievers/DOMContentRetriever.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/1.0/_/download/resources/jira.webresources:inline-layer/InlineLayer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/1.0/_/download/resources/jira.webresources:inline-layer/InlineLayer.OptionsDescriptor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/1.0/_/download/resources/jira.webresources:inline-layer/InlineLayer.create.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/1.0/_/download/resources/jira.webresources:inline-layer/InlineLayer.StandardPositioning.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/1.0/_/download/resources/jira.webresources:inline-layer/InlineLayer.IframePositioning.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/1.0/_/download/resources/jira.webresources:list/Group.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/1.0/_/download/resources/jira.webresources:list/ItemDescriptor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/1.0/_/download/resources/jira.webresources:list/GroupDescriptor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/1.0/_/download/resources/jira.webresources:list/List.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/1.0/_/download/resources/jira.webresources:autocomplete/JIRA.Dropdown.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/1.0/_/download/resources/jira.webresources:autocomplete/AutoComplete.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/1.0/_/download/resources/jira.webresources:autocomplete/RESTAutoComplete.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/1.0/_/download/resources/jira.webresources:autocomplete/IssueAutoComplete.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/1.0/_/download/resources/jira.webresources:autocomplete/UserAutoComplete.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/1.0/_/download/resources/jira.webresources:autocomplete/initAutoCompleteFields.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/1.0-SNAPSHOT/_/download/resources/com.teradata.jira.gadgets.defectgadget:defectgadget-resources/defectgadget.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/1.0-SNAPSHOT/_/download/resources/com.teradata.jira.gadgets.defectgadget:defectgadget-resources/barRenderer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/1.0-SNAPSHOT/_/download/resources/com.teradata.jira.gadgets.defectgadget:defectgadget-resources/categoryAxisRenderer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/1.0-SNAPSHOT/_/download/resources/com.teradata.jira.gadgets.defectgadget:defectgadget-resources/pointLabels.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
    (function () { //myscript accessing jqplot javascript in pointLabels.js etc.
})();
</script>
```

am I missing the order of js includes/links in the above list?
I want to check whether the scripts are loading or not by firebug, but I'm new to firebug, could you pls help me to do this. The above code is in iframe object. I'm able to see the code from firebug but unable to see it in script tab and unable to set breakpoints.

As suggested by jira people I have tried using AJS.$ instead of $. And I tried jQuery instead of $, but no luck.

Could you please help me on this?

Comment: You could start by browsing to http://winpj185013-mh7:2990/jira/s/en_US6c3e1m/734/3/3.5.5/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.auiplugin:jquery-lib/jquery.js and see if your browser is able to reach that file.

Comment: probably you need to put man jquery library on top.

Comment: view source of your page and check the loaded files...

Comment: Oops! My jqplot JS files has nothing when I view source. Is that mean it did not load?

Comment: all the js files are loading fine. but no luck, still same problem, $ is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to check the jquery file is included or not. The jQuery file should be included before other plugins.

You may use the JSViewer add on in firefox to see what are the script files are loaded.

Comment: all the js files are loading fine. but no luck, still same problem, $ is undefined.

Comment: my jquery.js is of 1.5.2, will that make any difference?

Comment: which line u are getting $ is undefined

Comment: Please see the code at(first code block copied into my script tag) http://www.jqplot.com/tests/bar-charts.php at 9th line.

Comment: please try with jQuery instead of $ and check once again how many jquery.js file is loaded in your page

Comment: tried to add jQuery.noConflict(); before 9th line, but no luck :(

Comment: do u check this ? jQuery instead of $ and check once again how many jquery.js file is loaded in your page

Comment: just checked, it is working fine(Thanks!) and moving to next $ and showing same error. But my concern is, I cannot change all these $ referenced in jqplot bundle(even I see the same error at all the points in jqplot JS files).

Comment: try with this $.noConflict() if it is not working means u have to change the $ as jQuery

Comment: FYI, jQuery is working at line 9, but not at line 13. Error is jQuery is undefined.

Comment: $.noConflict is not working(same $ is undefined error). jQuery.noConflict is working.

Comment: No! I have used jQuery.noConflict just before 9th line, so 9th line is fine, but getting $ is undefined at line 13 :(

Comment: simply solved by adding line(before 9th line): var $ = jQuery;

Comment: Thanks a lot Muthu for you help!